# I am Trying to send vaues from ajax to wcf to insert in mysql table

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, ajax, wcf

My code is working in IE and not working in Firefox and Chrome.

I'm troubleshooting this error as

```
http//localhost:54537/Service1.svc/insert Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Insert.aspx:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54537/Service1.svc/insert. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:54605' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

this is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>     
    <script src="Script/jquery1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#search").live("click", function () {

            var PatientName = $("#PatientName").val();
            var PatientDisease = $("#PatientDisease").val();
            var PatientAddress = $("#PatientAddress").val();
            var PatientDoB = $("#PatientDoB").val();            
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '<%=ResolveUrl("http://localhost:54537/Service1.svc/insert") %>',               
                data: JSON.stringify({ PatientName: PatientName, PatientDisease: PatientDisease, PatientAddress: PatientAddress,PatientDoB: PatientDoB }),
                processData: true,
                dataType: "json",          
                traditional:true,
                success: function (response) {               
                window.location="Edit.aspx";
                },
                error: function (a, b, c)
                 {
                    alert(a.responseText);
                 }
             });
        });
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
         <table style="height: 170px; width: 295px">  
          <tr>  
          <td>PatientName:</td>  
          <td><input type="text" id="PatientName"/></td>  
          </tr>
          <tr>  
          <td>PatientDisease:</td>  
          <td> <input type="text" id="PatientDisease"/></td>  
          </tr>  
                <tr>  
          <td>PatientAddress:</td>  
          <td><input type="text" id="PatientAddress"/></td>  
          </tr> 
                <tr>  
          <td>PatientDoB:</td>  
          <td><input type="text" id="PatientDoB"/></td>  
          </tr> 
              <tr>
                    <td>  
                        <input type="button" id="search" value="Submit"/> 
                    </td>                       
                </tr>   
          </table>      
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same-origin policy? Enable cross-origin requests.

Comment: whether Enable cross-origin requests  has to be done in application or in service

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are running both WCF application and web application with ajax in local development server.

As per Same origin policy you can not make ajax call to different one.

```
In computing, the same-origin policy is an important concept in the web application security model. Under the policy, a web browser permits scripts contained in a first web page to access data in a second web page, but only if both web pages have the same origin.
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Even though `server name(localhost)` is same,but `port` numbers are different.

Check below link for CORS.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing